# How to change autoresizing for particular controller from Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I found some of my view controllers have

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

in my storyboard source code. This was causing problem as I figured out later. It has to be

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
```

But I couldn't find how to change it from Interface Builder. Anybody knows which element in IB represents `autoresizingMask` tag?

Answer (score 1):

From Interface Builder, go to your storyboard and select the most outer view (from the Document Outline) of your ViewController and then go to the `Size Inspector` (ruler icon) and you can find those `autoresizingMask` attributes of the xml as `Autoresizing` in your Interface Builder.

`widhtSizable` (horizontal arrow) and `heightSizable` (vertical arrow) are the most inner arrows.

- If the `arrow is selected` it is a `fine line` and that means that the value for that will be `YES` in your XML file.
- In case the `arrow is not selected` (you can unselect it by clicking on it) it will be shown `more transparent` and with `dotted line`, that means that the value for that will be `NO` in your XML file.

Check this screenshot, although those lines will always be shown `red` I made them with different colors in the screenshot to let you better see that the horizontal one is width and the vertical one is height.

[image]

Same applies to the `outer most lines` shown as `I` or `|-|` and those applies to the `y` and `x` constraint that can be adjusted by autolayout automatically. You can select them or not depending on what is customisable by you or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Auto Layout disabled, it is under the Size inspector (little ruler icon on the right hand pane). But if you want to use Auto Layout, you need to fix your constraints so they accurately describe your desired UI.

Comment: I always use Auto Layout and it was there. I'm not sure how some controllers got different `autoresizingMask`. In IB I would be glad to fix them, without touching XML. But I see no difference in IB and see no way to fix it. So the question is it possible to fix this from IB?

Comment: Oh, I may have misspoken. Even if you are using auto layout, views with no constraints applied will still use autoresizing masks. Are you sure you have your layout constraints completely specified for the view in question?

Comment: The view I am talking about is the root view of VC. IB does show exactly same params for both views + some constraints that I used for inner view. So in IB they are identical. No word about non-auto-layout masks. I only figured out they debugging very strange issue, which lead me to check XML and pull my hair off to see they are different.

Comment: The containing view's size is not governed by what is in the xib. It only matters how it is used in code (or embedded in another xib).